# Why .indexOf() is returning -1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, return, indexof

```js
function mutation(arr) {
         var total = arr.map(function(x){return x.toLowerCase();});
          var sec = total[1];
            for(var i=0; i < sec.length; i++){
        //       console.log(sec[i]);
              console.log(total.indexOf(sec[i]));
          }
        }
        mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Help me understand it, please.
The line with

> console.log(sec[i]);

shows on the console each line per time the letters of 'hey' string. And that is Okay!
Now, what I need to know is why whem I cal 'sec[i]' in

> console.log(total.indexOf(sec[i]));

the output is all '-1' which means that the method .indexOf() hasn't found
any letter!

Comment: indexOf looks at whole elements on arrays, you're trying use it like the String version, but they are 2 different functions.

Comment: That's it! I am using the array version instead of the String one! Thank you @dandavis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking the `total` array against a single character. That means the length is unequal and a string with a length of more than one is not equal to a single character (string length 1).

Basically you do this:

> ```
> ["hello", "hey"].indexOf('h') // -1
> ["hello", "hey"].indexOf('e') // -1
> ["hello", "hey"].indexOf('y') // -1
> ```

If you like to check the first string with the characters of the second, then you need to specify the index.

```
console.log(total[0].indexOf(sec[i]));
                 ^^^
```

```js
function mutation(arr) {
    var total = arr.map(function (x) { return x.toLowerCase(); }),
        sec = total[1],
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sec.length; i++){
        console.log(sec[i], total[0].indexOf(sec[i]));
    }
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't able to find anything that is why you are getting -1.